# Using styles' border property consumes more memory when rendering?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

This maybe more like a general question than technical - Is using `border` properties through *styles* are more memory stressful (in situations) than creating a border by `backgroundColor` property? Please, consider this following two codes which I wants to bring into the comparison - and situation is having them inside a renderer component to RN list:

With *styles* border:

```
<View style={{width: 100, height: 20, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomBackgroundColor: '#cccccc'}}/>
```

vs.

```
<View style={{width: 100, height: 20}}/>
<View style={{width: 100, height: 1, backgroundColor: '#cccccc'}}/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a border, use the `border` property. It's what it's there for. I can't ever see a scenario where memory would even be of concern. However, if I had to comment on it, at first glance the `backgroundColor` one seems less efficient, since you'd have to render a second element.

Though honestly it just seems like if you're asking this question, and using hacks to create CSS effects that are already native, you're focusing on the wrong things or something has gone awry. However, since you didn't mention your specific use case I can't be certain.

Comment: Hi thanks! Yes, as I have mentioned the use cases (or scenario) is using them in renderer component to RN list. On some more information, I was using PureComponent to the renderer class.